# Dynamically made pages don't load actual page content/code

Tags: c#, wpf, loading, frame

I'm trying to create a modular way of loading pages, each page having it's own navigation menu item in the main window header and a separate frame to keep them always loaded in memory (and to play fancy animations etc.)

Here's the class that contains the loaded page.

```
 public sealed class PageContainer : Frame
{
    public string Title;

    public PageContainer(string Page, bool CustomUri = false)
    {
        Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed;
        NavigationUIVisibility = NavigationUIVisibility.Hidden;
        Title = Page;

        if(!CustomUri)
        {
            Navigate($"pack://lotus:,,,/Views/UserPages/{Page}.xaml", UriKind.Relative);
        }
        else
        {
            //todo
        }

        Console.WriteLine($"Navigation Item created {Title} with ?CustomUri: {CustomUri}");
    }

    public bool Visible
    {
        get => Visibility == System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
        set => Visibility = value ? System.Windows.Visibility.Visible : System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed;
    }
}
```

And here's how I'm creating the PageContainer(s)

```
Animations.PageTransitionAnimations AnimationLibrary;

    public double _SlideAnimationLenght = 250;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        //Initialize Animation Library
        AnimationLibrary = new Animations.PageTransitionAnimations(this);

        InitializePage("Library");
        InitializePage("Preferences");
        InitializePage("Plugins");
        InitializePage("Information");

        foreach(PageContainer pp in LoadedContainers)
        {
            pp.Visible = true;
            pp.BeginAnimation(MarginProperty, AnimationLibrary.ToLeft);
        }
    }

    //Load a page and add it to navigation bar, if NoHeader, then don't add it to navigation
    private void InitializePage(string page, bool noHeader = false)
    {
        if(!noHeader)
        {
            //Add page to navigation bar and set style
            NavigationHeader.Children.Add(new NavigationItem(page)
            {
                Style = FindResource("HeaderMenu") as System.Windows.Style
            });
        }

        //Add Page to PageContainer and Initialize it
        PageContainer _page = new PageContainer(page);

        _containers.Add(_page);
        PagesContainer.Children.Add(_page);
    }

    //Public LoadedContainers, no setter
    private List<PageContainer> _containers = new List<PageContainer>();
    public List<PageContainer> LoadedContainers => _containers;
```

What happens is that the navigation in PageContainer actually succeeds the navigation event, but frames don't report any content, page code doesn't execute and there's no design.

Any suggestions? Thanks.

Edit:

Pages themselves have no problems, because I load them manually, they do work. Also, here's the link to full code: https://github.com/FaithLV/lotus

Comment: What is the `lotus` URI scheme in your navigation URI?  Generally, a pack URI should use either `application` or `siteoforigin` for package part scheme.  Are you using a custom URI resolver?

Comment: Also, you're giving an **absolute** URI while specifying `UriKind.Relative`.  What happens if you specify a **relative** URI instead?  e.g., `"/Views/UserPages/{Page}.xaml"`.

Comment: @MikeStrobel don't think that I do, I've added link to code repo, if that helps clarifying the issue. thanks

Comment: @MikeStrobel Also, Relative UriKind doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was an issue with how I was navigating to the page.
Turns out, the "application" in URI wasn't context sensitive and actually is used as is.

Here's the correct way to navigation:

```
 Navigate(new Uri($"pack://application:,,,/Views/UserPages/{Page}.xaml"), UriKind.Absolute);
```